# Adding a ":" command inside autocmd in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd Filetype mkd call SetWritingOptions()
function SetWritingOptions()
  setlocal guioptions-=T
  colorscheme pencil
  setlocal background=light
endfunction
```

I have a plugin which I activate by doing `:VimroomToggle`

Now, I would like to add that to the `SetWritingOptions()` function, so `:VimroomToggle` gets called each time I open a `mkd` file. How to do that?

Comment: BTW, even `:setlocal` won't change the fact that these options are _global_ only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this line in the function:

```
VimroomToggle
```

Commands you call in functions are the same as functions you enter using the `:` leader.